# Detecting iPad Mouse Right Click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad, mouse

I have a tableView in my app and want to show a contextual menu in the app ONLY when the user right-clicks it with a mouse on their iPad.

The current `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration?` method shows the contextual menu for both right-click and long-pressing the item with a finger which is not the behavior I want. I want only a right-click from a mouse pointer.

Is there a way to detect if this function is being called from a right-click? I looked everywhere online and haven't found anything. Thank you in advance!